# Firebase Authentication routing in Polymer

Tags: polymer, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I'm currently building an app in Polymer which uses Firebase Authentication to login with your Google+ account or Email. When you run the app it will first check if the user already has a session. If not then the user is being routed to the login page which will display a login form and will handle the login by using `<firebase-auth>` by [Polymerfire](https://github.com/firebase/polymerfire). The login page will notify the `user` property upwards to the `my-app` (app shell). If the user has been successfully authenticated we send them to the homepage `my-app`. This will fire the `routePageChanged` observer in `my-app`.

```
_routePageChanged(page) {
    if(this.user && this.user.email && this.user.refreshToken) {
       this.set("noUser", false);
       this.page = page
    } else {
       this.set("noUser", true);
       this.page = 'login';
    }
}
```

Okay, so far so good. If we route a user to the login form and let them authenticate, all is working fine. However, if the user already has a session the `routePageChanged` observer in `my-app` will fire and won't have a user object ***yet***.

**Problem 1**

The problem in the example above is that it'll always show the login page for a few miliseconds. We can fix this by adding a timeout (?) on the initial route and show a spinner and wait for the firebase authentication. This seems a little bit hacky as I don't know how long it will take for the user to automatically authenticate? What is the best way to wait for the authentication and then do a route?

**Problem 2**

In the `app-login` page I'm handling the login. I've chosen to use a `singInWithRedirect` as I want the login to be available on mobile (popups are being blocked sometimes). The problem with  `singInWithRedirect` is that it'll also re-render/initialise the whole app after authentication. This means that after creating a valid auth session the `routePageChanged` observer in `my-app` will be fired and there won't be a user object for a few miliseconds, which will make the app route to `/login`.

The `_userChanged` function in `app-login` will then route back to the overview on its turn. This will also show the login page for a few miliseconds.

`<firebase-auth id="auth" user="{{user}}" provider="{{provider}}" on-error="handleError" on-user-changed="_userChanged"></firebase-auth>`

```
_userChanged(event) {
    if (event.detail.value.uid) {
       this.set("waitingForAuthChanged", false);
       this.set("user", event.detail.value);
       window.history.pushState({}, null, "/overview");
       window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('location-changed'));
    }
}
```

What's the best way to properly handle all these states? I used to use the `signInWithPopup` function, this won't initialise the app after authentication. I'm trying to achieve the same with the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

You use `routePageChanged` observer instead of `user` object observer. So try to manage all with observer of `user`:

```
<firebase-auth id="auth" user="{{user}}" provider="{{provider}}" on-error="handleError" on-user-changed="_userChanged"></firebase-auth>
...
<iron-pages role="main" selected="[[page]]" attr-for-selected="name" selected-attribute="visible" fallback-selection="404" > 
<div name="home"><my-home>Home Page</my-home></div>
<div name="signin"><signin-page>Signing page</signin-page></div>
<div name="404"></div>
</iron-pages>
...
<script>
...
static get observers() {
        return ['_isUserLoggedIn(user)']

... 
_isUserLoggedIn(u) {
    if (u) { this.set('signedIn', true);
             this.set('page', 'home'); // user signed in, then go home
            } else {
            this.set('signedIn', false);
            this.set('page', 'signin'); // user not signed in, so go sign in page
            }
}
</script>
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/cappittall/pen/VQwbGe)

Comment: Thanks Hakan! Correct me if I'm wrong but then you'll still have the same problem right?
If the user enters the app the user object will be empty, this would mean that he'll gets redirected to the signin page, if you had a session already then he'll see the login page for a few miliseconds and then hits the isUserLoggedIn observer where he'll be redirected to the homepage

Comment: There may some other ways, but  check the demo  link for  (below of my answer)

Comment: Thanks HakanC, the demo you provided me with is exactly demonstrating my problem. When I open your app it'll show the signin page for a few miliseconds and will then route back to home. This is because of the timeout that'll set the user after 1.5s. In my case: if an user has been logged in before and didn't logout then it will still have a session. This would mean that the the user object will be set after 'x' seconds. I'm looking for some best practices to wait for that so that I could load resources in the meanwhile, show a spinner, hide some content etc. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: If you do not want to wait for even some millisecond, you may save the `signedIn` to local store upon the user has signed in ones. And next time your app will check local storage if `signedIn` property exists or not. And if exist than direct to homepage directly. The user will wait for just ones.